# How to redirect to a page and then execute a jQuery function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to redirect to page then execute a function with some parameters.

For Example:
Page1.js

```
if (condition is true) {
    window.location.href("Index","Page2");
    someFunction();
}
```

Is there a way to capture the redirection and execute the function in Page2

Kindly help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply pass query parameters in your url when you redirect, assuming your using the same javascript file for both pages.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try this javascript:

**Page 1:**

```js
if (true) {
   window.open("page2.html?myVar1=42&myVar2=66", '_blank');
}
```

**Page 2:**

```js
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

var v1 = urlParams.get('myVar1');
var v2 = urlParams.get('myVar2');

function someFunction(myVar1, myVar2){
  console.log(myVar1);
  console.log(myVar2);
}

someFunction(v1, v2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not working for me because the function is in Page 2

Comment: @Palani, you can use this as well. I didn't notice an important thing of your question. I have edited my solution.

Comment: Thanks this was better for my case. Is there any way to hide the query string

Comment: @Palani, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

**Page1 Code :**

```
if (condition is true) {

   window.location.href = '/yourpage2?act=runfunc';

}
```

**Page2 Code:**

```
<script>
var qParam = getUrlParameter('act');

if (qParam=='runfunc') {
someFunction();
}

function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
</script>
```